# Remove duplicates from combobox

Tags: delphi

Say i have a combobox with

```
apples
apples
pears
oranges
oranges
```

i would like to have it show

```
apples
pears
oranges
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Zarko has a good article on the subject. http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/remove-duplicat.htm

Comment: @GX - The side effect of suggested code is possibly changed order of strings.

Comment: @G-Man The link is not available now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for iter := combobox.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  index := combobox.Items.IndexOf(combobox.Items[iter]);
  if index < iter then
    combobox.Items.Delete(iter);
end;
```

Comment: Oops, typed directly into SO. Wrap the for loop in combobox.Items.BeginUpdate/combobox.Items.EndUpdate for performance.

Comment: While an effective and simple method, watch out when using this with larger lists. Even with only a few thousand entries this method will become really slow.

Comment: There might be some misses in the code. if there are 3 occurences of one item only one of them would be deleted. there should be a repeat statement around   repeat `index := combobox.Items.IndexOf(combobox.Items[iter]);
  if index < iter then
    combobox.Items.Delete(iter);` until index < 0 ;

Comment: I don't see mistakes in the code, except for the n^2 running time. Indexof in worst case will check all other elements. You call indexof on every element in the list. For 100 elements there are 10.000 comparissons, most of which are useless. If your list fills to 10.000 elements you will have 100.000.000 comparissons and your applications will slow down to a crawl. A smarter algorithm would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you simply refill the combo box each time. That makes the logic simpler:

```
ComboBox.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  ComboBox.Clear;
  for Str in Values do
    begin
    if ComboBox.Items.IndexOf (Str) = -1 then
      ComboBox.Items.Add (Str);
    end;
finally
  ComboBox.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to put methods against eachother: one keeps the order but is increasingly slow with larger number of items. The other stays relatively faster but doesn't keep order:

```
procedure SortStringlist;
var
  i,index,itimer: integer;
  sl : TStringlist;
const
  numberofitems = 10000;
begin
  sl := TStringlist.Create;
  for i := 0 to numberofitems-1 do begin
    sl.Add(IntToStr(random(2000)));
  end;
  Showmessage(IntToStr(sl.Count));

  itimer := GetTickCount;
  sl.Sort;
  for I := sl.Count-1 downto 1 do begin
    if sl[i]=sl[i-1] then sl.Delete(i);
  end;
  Showmessage(IntToStr(sl.Count)+' Time taken in ms: '+IntToStr(GetTickCount-itimer));
  sl.free;
  sl := TStringlist.Create;
  for i := 0 to numberofitems-1 do begin
    sl.Add(IntToStr(random(2000)));
  end;
  Showmessage(IntToStr(sl.Count));

  itimer := GetTickCount;
  for i := sl.Count - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
  index := sl.IndexOf(sl[i]);
  if index < i then
    sl.Delete(i);
  end;
  Showmessage(IntToStr(sl.Count)+' Time taken in ms: '+IntToStr(GetTickCount-itimer));
end;
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `try SL.BeginUpdate..finally SL.EndUpdate` to lock the updates.

Comment: Is that needed for a non-visual object?

Comment: Sorry, taking back. With `TStringList` it's not necessary, I've mistaken your `SL` with combo box items. I have to take a break :-)

Comment: it's just, I've lately been working on a project where I've had a headache with some dictionary object slowing the project down which came down to the "slow" kind of getting rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care if the items get reordered (or they're sorted already), `TStrings` can do the work for you - it eliminates all of the looping, deletion, and other work. (Of course, it requires the creation/destruction of a temporary `TStringList`, so if that's an issue for you it won't work.)

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.Sorted := True; // Required for Duplicates to work
      SL.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
      SL.AddStrings(ComboBox1.Items);
      ComboBox1.Items.Assign(SL);
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

To properly compare with Igor's answer (which includes no `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate`), remove those things:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Sorted := True; // Required for Duplicates to work
    SL.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
    SL.AddStrings(ComboBox1.Items);
    ComboBox1.Items.Assign(SL);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove duplicates from the source data.

In most scenarios, a ComboBox is filled with data in run-time, which means, data is coming from some source. There are basically 2 scenarios here: a dataset from database and a collection of strings from any other source. In both cases you filter out duplicates before inserting anything into the ComboBox.

If source is a dataset from database, simply use the SQL `DISTINCT` keyword.

If source is any collection of strings, use a peace of code provided in the answer by @Smasher.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem several times before, and i used all the previous approaches and I'm still using them, but do you know : i think the best approach , though not mentioned here, is to subclass TComboBox, creating a new method (say AddUnique ) that add the string to the combo ONLY if it does not exist previously , otherwise it will drop it. 
This solution may cost some extra time in the beginning , but it will solve the problem once and for all.